# SQL Selecting Values not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a chemistry database (very small, about 60kb or so) in a mysql database. My

```
select * from firstdatabase;
```

works fine with any column but symbol. When I do

```
select * from firstdatabase where symbol = "Y";
```

for example, I get an empty set. However, when I do

```
select symbol from firstdatabase;
```

I get every symbol in the database including "Y". This problem doesn't occur with any other field except symbol. I have also tried it with double lettered and triple lettered elements to no avail. Please help?

Comment: what is the output of 'desc firstdatabase'?

Comment: I actually fixed the problem using an answer below. It was that I had whitespaces. But thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess is your `symbol` column contains whitespace characters. So you should try `TRIM` function.

```
select * from firstdatabase where TRIM(symbol) = "Y"
```

Comment: And then you should fix your data and data entry protocol so that white spaces aren't included

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. That works perfectly. And I will try to remove any whitespace throughout the database using PHP or Python. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I got it through mysql itself

Answer (score 0):

Use [LTRIM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_ltrim) and [RTRIM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_rtrim) if there whitespace characters in your symbol column.You should try `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` function.

```
select * from firstdatabase where  LTRIM(RTRIM(symbol))= 'Y'
```

Comment: Because two functions are better than one?

Comment: Sorry, I meant thank you, but Theim's TRIM works both at once